# Is any way to run pyinstaller command from anther python script when condition satisfies?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I can able to create python script to exe file using pyinstaller command as,

`pyinstaller my_script.py`

Now I tried to create exe file from another python script when condition satisfied,

```
if conditon == True:
     run pyinstaller command
else:
     pass
```

Answer (score 3):

To run a pyinstaller command from a python script you can use the `PyInstaller.__main__` modal and pass command line arguments through the `.run` function as a list.
the code looks like this.

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    '--name=%s' % package_name,
    '--onefile',
    '--windowed',
    '--add-binary=%s' % os.path.join('resource', 'path', '*.png'),
    '--add-data=%s' % os.path.join('resource', 'path', '*.txt'),
    '--icon=%s' % os.path.join('resource', 'path', 'icon.ico'),
    os.path.join('my_package', '__main__.py'),
])
```

More information can be found [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20run,in%20as%20a%20list%2C%20e.g.).

Answer (score 1):

One interesting concept from subprocess module works for me

```
import subprocess

if create_exe == True:
   subprocess.call(r"python -m PyInstaller -F --name test --add-data 
   templates;templates --add-data static;static --icon=icon.ico path\to\test.py")
else:
   pass
```

where,

**--name** --> Put the name of exe file you want to create

**--add-data** --> to add the static files

**--icon** --> to set the icon for your exe files

**path\to\test.py** --> give the path of python file you want to convert as exe